# Concatenate and use in where clause oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to concatenate two fields and use concatenated field in where clause but it gives me invalid identifier. How to solve this query.

```
select i.FIRST_NAME || ' - ' || i.LAST_NAME as NAME, i.* from CONTACT i 
where NAME = 'JOHN - HANKS'
```

This gives me

```
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias at the same level.  Just use a subquery (or repeat the expression):

```
select c.*
from (select i.FIRST_NAME || ' - ' || i.LAST_NAME as NAME, i.*
      from CONTACT i 
     ) c
where c.NAME = 'JOHN - HANKS';
```

Answer (score 3):

The WITH clause is also a good alternative, better readability. Also, if the subquery is to be used multiple times, it is even better.

```
WITH data as(
   select i.FIRST_NAME || ' - ' || i.LAST_NAME as NAME, i.* from CONTACT i)
select  * from data where name = 'JOHN - HANKS';
```

Answer (score -2):

select i.FIRST_NAME || ' - ' || i.LAST_NAME as NAME, i.* from CONTACT i
where i.first_name ||'~'||i.last_name = 'JHON~HANKS';